# How can I make infowindows resize for tweets in Google Maps v3 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to add a few tweets to an infowindow in Google Maps. I get the tweets to display in a div that is the content of my infowindow, but it's the wrong size.

I thought by calling '**content_changed**' when the marker is clicked, the infowindow would resize - it doesn't.

I'm sure this is pretty straightforward, can someone help me out?

Thanks,

James

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.500261,-0.126793);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow.setContent(document.getElementById("station"));

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(infowindow, 'content_changed');
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `infowindow.close();` before `open()`. I'm pretty sure that it will force it to rerender

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a supported solution, but after poking around in Firebug, I found an easy way to force a resize on the window:

```
infoWindow.b.contentSize = new google.maps.Size(w, h);
google.maps.event.trigger(infoWindow.b, 'contentsize_changed');
```

As far as what the real W/H should be set to on the first line, that's a matter of looking at `infoWindow.b.contentNode` and getting a real width/height either through the standard properties or jQuery's methods.

I'm not sure exactly what `infoWindow.b` is, but it seems like it's some sort of "content" object.  I wish they would expose this and document it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
infoWindowLinea.setContent(infoWindowLinea.getContent());
```